# Refreshing Route - Render screen only when it has been displayed (FIXED)

Tags: react-native

I am using the stack navigator and I have a data-heavy screen that I re-navigate to couple of times. 
However, the screens in between seem to lack in performance because that data is still running in the background.

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
 onLoad = () => {
    this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => console.log('x'))
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.onLoad()
  }
```

EDIT: I fixed it by using navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset) function

Comment: use this https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `react-navigation`'s HOC `withNavigationFocus`.

Simply import it

```
import {withNavigationFocus} from "react-navigation"
```

and then export it doing

```
export default withNavigationFocus(ComponentName)
```

After that, inside your `componentDidUpdate`, check about the `isFocused` prop and do what you need. For example:

```
componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    if (this.props.isFocused !== prevProps.isFocused){ //If the focused state changed
    //do whatever you need to do like:
    if(this.props.isFocused === false) this.setState({stopLoadingData: false})
    else this.setState({stopLoadingData: false})
    }
}
```

You can read more about it in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation-focus.html)

Comment: Hi, looks great. However, I get an error 'no overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 3.....'  class MYCOMPONENT extends React.Component<MYCOMPONENTProps>  and i export it in the following way: export default withNavigationFocus(MYCOMPONENT)

Comment: Can you post the code for your component? Is it connected to redux?